# Spell Sniper and spells with saves

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats

The second bullet point of the Spell Sniper feat says:

> Your ranged spell attacks ignore half cover and three-quarters cover.

What is a "ranged spell attack", in this case?
Does that mean ranged spells that have an attack roll, or ranged spells that deal damage?

Or, to get right to the point: does Spell Sniper allow my *fireball* to ignore the bonus to Dexterity saving throws that cover normally affords?

Comment: Side note: Given that a fireball spell spreads around corners, does partial (or even full) cover actually help at all against it?

Comment: @RyanThompson It doesn't say cover _doesn't_ help. Apply the appropriate level of physical reasoning for your player group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Spells that use ranged spell attacks will say that.

A ranged spell attack is a ranged attack roll<sup>1</sup> to hit with a spell. *Eldritch blast*, for example, says "Make a ranged spell attack."

Spells that have attack rolls typically don't allow saves (not against their main effect, at least).  Like any attack roll, the difficulty for a spell attack roll is based on the target's AC and gets *a bonus for partial cover*.   Spell Sniper negates that bonus.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Attack Rolls](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=76)

> When you make an attack, your attack roll determines whether the attack hits or misses. To make an attack roll, roll a d20 and add the appropriate modifiers. {snip}    Some spells also require an attack roll. The ability modifier used for a spell attack depends on the spellcasting ability of the spellcaster, as explained in chapter 10. (Basic Rules, p. 76)  - 
>   Some spells [require the caster to make an attack roll](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=85) to determine whether the spell effect hits the intended target. Your attack bonus with a spell attack equals your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus. (Basic Rules, p. 85)

Comment: Solid answer, I just added a ref.

Answer (score 1):

Throughout the Player's Handbook, the phrase "spell attack" is used to specifically refer to spells that have an attack roll, including in the spellcasting class descriptions where it specifies your **spell attack bonus** as distinct from your **spell save DC**. A "ranged spell attack" is a spell that has a range longer than touch and has an attack roll.

Comment: It might be helpful to link to/quote the section of the spellcasting chapter on attack rolls, which defines how spell attacks work: https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#AttackRolls